# Low search to implement multiple channel entries

Tags: low-search

I have a problem in retrieving data from different channel field.

i want to search all enteries of news to check if its matched. Please tell me how i Can do that. I am writing my code below.

Below code is working for a single channel entry and not for multiple

```
{exp:low_search:form
     collection="news" 
     search_mode="any"
     result_page="news/view"}
     <div id="txthint">dqwdqq</div>
     <input type="text" class="search-query input-small" name="search:title"  id="search:title" >
{/exp:low_search:form}

{exp:low_search:results 
    query="{segment_3}" 
    limit="10"}
    {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
        <li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
    {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
    {if no_results}Geen resultaten gevonden{/if}

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Search's Form tag doesn't take any filter parameters, at least [not since v3](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs#to-3.0). You're defining 2 filter parameters (`collection` and `search_mode`) on the Form tag, but you should add these parameters to the Results tag or add them as (hidden) input fields in side the Form tag.

Also, I'd recommend using `name="keywords"` (utilizing the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords)) instead of `name="search:title"` (which is the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search)).